# Webdriver Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, ant, testng

I'm getting the error below. Actually when I run my suite file directly it works fine but when I try to run through build.xml it shows me the error. 
Details :Windows 7, 64 bit, FF 37.0.2, Selenium Server standalone-2.44

---

```
  org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms. Firefox console output:
           [testng]     DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Starting write
           [testng] 1430823821029   addons.manager  DEBUG   shutdown
           [testng] 1430823821030   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
           [testng] 1430823821030   addons.xpi  DEBUG   shutdown
           [testng] 1430823821030   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   shutdown
           [testng] 1430823821030   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
           [testng] 1430823821031   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
           [testng] 1430823821032   addons.manager  DEBUG   Calling shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
           [testng] 1430823821422   DeferredSave.extensions.json    DEBUG   Write succeeded
           [testng] 1430823821422   addons.xpi-utils    DEBUG   XPI Database saved, setting schema version preference to 16
           [testng] 1430823821423   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Notifying XPI shutdown observers
           [testng] 1430823821426   addons.manager  DEBUG   Async provider shutdown done
           [testng] 1430823822007   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/addons/XPIProvider.jsm: ["XPIProvider"]
           [testng] 1430823822009   addons.manager  DEBUG   Loaded provider scope for resource://gre/modules/LightweightThemeManager.jsm: ["LightweightThemeManager"]
           [testng] 1430823822011   addons.xpi  DEBUG   startup
           [testng] 1430823822012   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping fxdriver@googlecode.com to C:\Users\lp305\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous3559432167308222757webdriver-profile\extensions\fxdriver@googlecode.com
           [testng] 1430823822012   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Ignoring file entry whose name is not a valid add-on ID: C:\Users\lp305\AppData\Local\Temp\anonymous3559432167308222757webdriver-profile\extensions\webdriver-staging
           [testng] 1430823822013   addons.xpi  INFO    Mapping {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} to C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\browser\extensions\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
           [testng] 1430823822013   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-share
           [testng] 1430823822014   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Skipping unavailable install location app-system-local
           [testng] 1430823822014   addons.xpi  DEBUG   checkForChanges
           [testng] 1430823822015   addons.xpi  DEBUG   Loaded add-on state from prefs: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\lp305\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous3559432167308222757webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":true,"v":"2.44.0","st":1430823818166,"mt":1430823817961}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"37.0.2","st":1430726266335,"mt":1430726265855}}}
           [testng] 1430823822016   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of fxdriver@googlecode.com
           [testng] 1430823822022   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getModTime: Recursive scan of {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}
           [testng] 1430823822023   addons.xpi  DEBUG   getInstallState changed: false, state: {"app-profile":{"fxdriver@googlecode.com":{"d":"C:\\Users\\lp305\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\anonymous3559432167308222757webdriver-profile\\extensions\\fxdriver@googlecode.com","e":true,"v":"2.44.0","st":1430823818166,"mt":1430823817961}},"app-global":{"{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}":{"d":"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\browser\\extensions\\{972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd}","e":true,"v":"37.0.2","st":1430726266335,"mt":1430726265855}}}
           [testng] 1430823822024   addons.xpi  DEBUG   No changes found
           [testng] 1430823822028   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for XPIProvider
           [testng] 1430823822028   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for LightweightThemeManager
           [testng] 1430823822030   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for GMPProvider
           [testng] 1430823822031   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for PluginProvider
           [testng] JavaScript error: file:///C:/Users/lp305/AppData/Local/Temp/anonymous3559432167308222757webdriver-profile/extensions/fxdriver@googlecode.com/components/driver-component.js, line 11487: TypeError: this.server_ is undefined
           [testng] JavaScript error: chrome://fxdriver/content/server.js, line 38: NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80570015 (NS_ERROR_XPC_CI_RETURNED_FAILURE) [nsIJSCID.createInstance]
           [testng] *** Blocklist::_preloadBlocklistFile: blocklist is disabled
           [testng] 1430823823429   addons.manager  DEBUG   Registering shutdown blocker for <unnamed-provider>
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.NewProfileExtensionConnection.start(NewProfileExtensionConnection.java:118)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.startClient(FirefoxDriver.java:246)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:114)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:193)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:186)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:182)
           [testng]     at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:95)
           [testng]     at lowLevel.GeneralMethods.getBrowser(GeneralMethods.java:86)
           [testng]     at highLevel.WebLogin.beforeClass(WebLogin.java:18)
           [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
           [testng]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           [testng]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
           [testng]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:564)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:213)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:653)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:901)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1231)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
           [testng]     at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
           [testng]     at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1364)
           [testng]     at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1333)
           [testng] ===============================================
           [testng] testNG
           [testng] Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 1
           [testng] Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 1
           [testng] ===============================================
           [testng] The tests failed.


            BUILD SUCCESSFUL
            Total time: 54 seconds
```

Comment: which firefox version you are using?

Comment: @HelpingHands FF 37.0.2

Comment: Actually selenium web driver 2.44 support till firefox 33 version...so you will need to go back to firefox old version or use chrome..  you can see selenium support here : https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG

Comment: @HelpingHands Thank you for your prompt reply, I will check and update here

Comment: @HelpingHands But scripts run successfully if I run suite directly but above errors occurs only when I run suite via ant build tool (build.xml)

Comment: I understand but try once with chrome using xml to identify more specific issue.

Comment: @HelpingHands Okay, I will check and update here, Thank you :)

Comment: @HelpingHands : Hey, Thanks you so much, I was struggling from last three days to resolve this problem. Finally you did it. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The issue happens due to **incompatibility between Selenium Server and
Firefox browser**.

Mostly, this is displayed when browser is updated and existing Selenium Server do not support the new version.

The solution is to upgrade the Selenium server to the latest version.

**Reference:**

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=6215

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7810

https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=7819